# Couldn't understand the Ruby command-line switch -0digit

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

From the [doc](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/options.html)

***-0digit =>***

*specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal number. If no digits given, the null character is the separator. Other switches may follow the digits. -00 turns Ruby into paragraph mode. -0777 makes Ruby read whole file at once as a single string, since there is no legal character with that value.*

My bad! Couldn't digest it at all. So let's started to play with it.

```
C:\>ruby -0777 -e 'a= gets; puts a '
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here?
^Z #~~~> pressed ENTER here after CTRL+Z and got the output as below-
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here?
C:\>ruby #~~~> return the prompt

C:\>ruby -000 -e 'a= gets; puts a '
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here?
^Z #~~~> pressed ENTER here after CTRL+Z and got the output as below-
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here?
C:\>ruby #~~~> return the prompt

C:\>ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a '
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here? #~~~> pressed ENTER
#~~~> pressed ENTER here and got the output as below-
Hi, This is Ram.
Could you help me here?
C:\>ruby #~~~> return the prompt
```

**Question: 1 -** Can I set such `octal` or `$/` to as below ?

```
carraige return (\r)
tab (\t)
```

If so, Can I have one example for each to see their behaviours?

***Question: 2*** - I also tried to print the value of `"$/"` and nothing printed. So how should I see that?

```
C:\>ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/}"'
hi

hi

here is:


C:\>ruby -0777 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/}"'
Hey! Arjun
Are you going school?

^Z
Hey! Arjun
Are you going school?

here is:

C:\>
```

Comment: can anyone please validate my answer? or if any more I need to put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Using as](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/as_34.html)

***Finally I found out the way about how to set the*** `carraige return (\r) and tab (\t)`.

Find the below code:

```
C:\>ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hi

Hi

here is: "\n\n"

C:\>ruby -015 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
hi
hi
^Z
hi
hi
here is: "\r"

C:\>ruby -011 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hello

^Z
Hello

here is: "\t"

C:\>
```

***Finally I could print with `.inspect` as below :***

```
C:\>ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hi

Hi

here is: "\n\n"

C:\>
```

Want to share my whole day's with ruby : :)

From the above link : [ASCII Code](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html)

I got the octal code of many more escape characters and also played with them with Ruby command line `-0<digit>` option:

Here is the full list of example.. read and digest it. :)

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -010 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
This is a spoon. Do you need it.^H
This is a spoon. Do you need it.
here is: "\b"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -033 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hi..How are you?
Are you going ^[ school today?
Hi..How are you?
Are you going 
here is: "\e"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -011 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Today is very hot outside   the room
Today is very hot outside   
here is: "\t"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -015 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Are you mad?hey..^Mhello..I am telling you dude...
Are you mad?hey..
here is: "\r"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -012 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Are you there?
Are you there?
here is: "\n"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -040 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Iammmmmmmmmm a
Iammmmmmmmmm 
here is: " "

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -014 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Earth is an planet.Remember it...^L dear brother
Earth is an planet.Remember it...

here is: "\f"

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -000 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hiiiii............

Hiiiii............

here is: "\n\n"
@ubuntu:~$
```